# Disable ACF in ckeditor not working

Tags: ckeditor

I want to disable advance content filtering in CKEDITOR. I tried some thing like :

```
allowedContent = true
```

It is not working. I want to stop converting `onclick` attribute into `data-cke-pa-onclick`, which bind with custom `DOM` (which i have added in `ckeditor` dynamically). I am working with angularjs and want to call an angular method from onclick event.